# Sorting categorical labels in seaborn chart

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, seaborn

I'm sure this should be easy, but I can't find in the seaborn documentation how I specifically choose the order of my x label categorical variables which are to be displayed?

I have hours worked per week as follows below, but I want to order these on my x axis from 0-10, 11-20, 21-30, 31-40 and More than 40 hours. How can I do this?

```
def hours_per_week (x):
if x < 11: return '0-10 hours'
elif x < 21: return '11-20 hours'
elif x < 31: return '21-30 hours'
elif x < 41: return '31-40 hours'
else: return 'More than 40 hours'
```

This is my seaborn code to plot the chart. Note 'income-cat' is a categorical grouping of people earning **under 50K** and those earning **above 50K**

```
plot_income_cat_hours = sns.countplot(x='hours_per_week_grouping',
                                      hue='income-cat', data=data)
```

This is currently how my plot looks (with some additional formatting not included in the code above because not relevant):
[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Set the [`order`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html#:%7E:text=order%2C%20hue_orderlists) parameter.

```
plot_income_cat_hours = sns.countplot(x='hours_per_week_grouping',
                        hue='income-cat', data=data, order=['place the desired order here'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following,

```
sns.countplot(data = data.sort_values(by="hours_per_week_grouping"), 
              x= "hours_per_week_grouping", hue= "income-cat")
```